# Subtracting Binary two Approaches

Tags: binary

looking for a second approach to binary subtraction. 
Been thinking and researching but can't think of a second approach.

I only have
16-1=15
 10000
-00001
=01111=15

simple subtraction as the first approach. Does anyone know if theres more approaches to this? I havn't been able to find anything in research :(

Comment: What do you mean by "more approaches"?

Comment: Im not quite sure myself, its a question on an assignment. Im not allowed to post the actual question on forums as i have to find the answer... I know that one approach to subtracting a number from another is binary subtraction. I have been hinted that it may require other operations (subtraction, addition, multiplication)... at this point im lost haha. Could it possibly be adding a positive binary and a twos complement binary to get the exact same answer as using binary subtraction? Hmmm ...

Comment: Bump bump bump plz halp xx